# Syntax error on the else of an IF-ELSE statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error on this one specific "else". I have no idea what the problem is. If it's not clear enough already, it's the else on line 16. I just started python a few days ago. So, don't face palm too hard please.

```
W = 1
while W == 1:
    if MH > 0:
        PlayerInput = input("Attack, Defend, or Run('1','2',or'3'):")
        if PlayerInput == "3":
            W = 0
        elif PlayerInput == "1": #Attack
            Atk = randint(1,4)
            if Atk == 1:
                Atk = randint(1,4)
                if Atk == 1:
                    print ("Miss")
                else:
                    MH = MH-((1/2)*FightingAbility)        
                    print ("Enemy lost %s Health" % ((1/2)*FightingAbility)
            else:<<<<---------[[This else is giving me trouble]]
                MH = MH-Fightingability
                print ("Enemy lost %s Health" % (FightingAbility))
        elif PlayerInput == "2": #Defend   
            if S > FightingAbility: #Enemy is stronger
                Def = randint(1,4)
                if Def == 1:
                    Def = randint(1,4)
                    if Def == 1:
                        print ("The %s Missed" % (E))
                    else:
                        Health = Health-((1/2)*S)        
                        print ("You lost %s Health" % ((1/2)*S)
                else:
                    Health = Health-S
                    print ("You lost %s Health" % (S))
            elif S <= FightingAbility: #Enemy is weaker
                Def = randint(1,4)
                if Def == 1:
                    Def = randint(1,4)
                    if Def == 1:
                        Health = Health-S
                        print ("You lost %s Health" % (S))
                    else:
                        Health = Health-((1/2)*S)        
                        print ("You lost %s Health" % ((1/2)*S)
                else:
                    print ("The %s Missed" % (E))
    else:
        Win=1
        pass
```

Comment: I believe you have been down voted, for providing a short code sample. You should simplify your code down to the simplest form that has the problem, before posting on S.O. In this case, doing so would have probably helped you solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`print` line (before `else`) does not have a closing parenthesis.

```
print ("Enemy lost %s Health" % ((1/2)*FightingAbility)
```